# PayPal Pro + Cardinal. Where to find the test credentials?

Tags: paypal, 3d-secure

I am trying to integrate PayPal Pro + Cardinal (3D secure). When registering with Cardinal, they do not send test credentials. Where can I find them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Production credentials for Cardinal testing.

Cardinal support takes over a week to reply, not worth dealing with them unless it is absolutely necessary.